# Passing item from list to a subprocess command

Tags: python

I am storing list of numbers into a list which I want to add to a command using a for loop. For example:

```
offNumber = ["111", "222"]

def offNumbers():
    for x in offsetList:
        p = subprocess.Popen (f"warc index C:\User\file1 {offNumber}, universal_newlines=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)"
        stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
        print(stdout)
    print(x)

offNumbers()
```

I want to add the offNumber which is stored in the list to a command which completes the command and iterate using for loop. I have written the code above but it just prints out the offNumber to the terminal and not the output of a command.

Any suggestions.

Comment: just fundamented guess but i think your 5th line is wrong, you end your string waaaaay to late i assume

Comment: and i also assume you wanted to indent `print(x)` by one tab aswell.

Comment: Do you want a separate subprocess for each number in the loop, or do you want to pass the while list to one subprocess?

Comment: i assume he wants to do separate commands, otherwise he wouldnt need a for loop

Comment: You want to avoid `Popen` when you can. You are reimplementing `subprocess.check_output`, poorly.

Comment: @KennyOstrom Yes I want a separate subprocess for each number in the loop. Thanks.

Comment: @tripleee Thanks. Are there any other options to run a command and taking a  new offset using a list?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question.

Comment: Show us what the commands you want to generate are; compare them against the commands _actually_ being generated. We know what your code _actually does_, but nobody but you knows _what you want it to do_. Don't make us guess.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you, i fixed the things mentioned in my comments.

```py
offNumber = ["111", "222"]

def offNumbers():
    for idx,x in enumerate(offsetList):
        p = subprocess.Popen(f"warc index C:\User\file{idx} {offNumber}", universal_newlines=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
        print(F"{x}:\n\n{stdout}")

offNumbers()
```

Comment: No this just returns an output: 
111: 

111

The command need to have the offset number i.e the command should look like
"warc index C:\User\file1 111" and the next command "warc index C:\User\file1 222" so and so forth.  I want to run each command in its own subprocess.

Comment: I edited it, do you want this? you need to better explain what you wish to accomplish

Answer (score 0):

Here's a demo with `subprocess.check_call`. Since you were not saving the output for anything, capturing it just so you can then print it seems pointless; let the output spill to the user's console right away instead.

```
offNumber = ["111", "222"]

def offNumbers():
    for x in offsetList:
        print(x)
        subprocess.check_call(f"warc index C:\User\file1 {offNumber}"

offNumbers()
```

You haven't revealed what the expected output should be exactly, so I had to guess a bit.